# releasing objects inside block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

This is regarding use of `__block` for releasing an object inside block;

```
NSString *str = [SomeObject methodName]; // returned object is autoreleased
[str retain];   //retaining the object since its auto released
```

Now i will be using this `str` object inside a block. inside block i will be releasing this object.
Do i need to prefix with like `__block NSString *str = ..`, since iam releasing it inside block?
From the rules i understand that if we want to modify an object inside block we need to prefix with `__block`. But does this rule applies for releasing also?

Comment: You shouldn't be retaining stuff outside the block and releasing them inside the block. Memory management in Cocoa is local. Every scope is only responsible for itself. The body of the block didn't retain it, so shouldn't release it. Plus, there is no guarantee that a block will be run (in which case there will be a leak if it's responsible for releasing it), or it may run more than once (in which case it will be over-released).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `__block` is required for *variables* you want to modify. Releasing an object doesn't mean modifying a variable. Rather, it means sending a `release` message to the object in question. Just as with any other message, there's no reason you can't send `release` to an object instance inside a block, even without the `__block` qualifier.

You should be aware that for non-`__block` qualified object variables, the block will retain the object. So, while your explicit `release` inside the block may balance a `retain` outside/before the block is invoked, the object won't actually be released (at least) until the block itself is released, even if no other object has retained it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is there any side effect of using __block qualifier even if you are not modifying object inside block?

Comment: I just edited my answer (which you may not have seen before commenting) to mention that __block will cause the block itself to not retain the object in question. There's a really good post that includes this info here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html